# nodejs connecting to hbase via phoenix and druid

Tags: java, node.js, jdbc, hbase, apache-phoenix

I have Phoenix installed phoenix-4.3.1 and successfully connected to it to hbase via sqline 
Both on a machine that is part of the cluster as well as a machine that is not part of the cluster and has no hadoop components; just access to zookeeper
sqlline access is fine, but connecting via app (npm) via druid is running into an error

I found npm
https://github.com/gaodazhu/phoenix-client

I am getting the following

```
May 22, 2015 2:08:25 AM com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource error
SEVERE: dataSource init error
java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver
        at com.alibaba.druid.util.JdbcUtils.createDriver(JdbcUtils.java:514)
        at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource.init(DruidDataSource.java:565)
        at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource.getConnection(DruidDataSource.java:878)
        at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource.getConnection(DruidDataSource.java:874)
        at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource.getConnection(DruidDataSource.java:97)
        at com.mlsc.DBClient.query(DBClient.java:134)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
        at com.alibaba.druid.util.JdbcUtils.createDriver(JdbcUtils.java:512)
        ... 9 more

May 22, 2015 2:08:25 AM com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource info
INFO: {dataSource-1} inited
java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver
        at com.alibaba.druid.util.JdbcUtils.createDriver(JdbcUtils.java:514)
        at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource.init(DruidDataSource.java:565)
        at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource.getConnection(DruidDataSource.java:878)
        at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource.getConnection(DruidDataSource.java:874)
        at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource.getConnection(DruidDataSource.java:97)
        at com.mlsc.DBClient.query(DBClient.java:134)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
        at com.alibaba.druid.util.JdbcUtils.createDriver(JdbcUtils.java:512)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried create a 'TEST' table in Phoenix? And make sure to insert some rows into the 'TEST' table.